# Deployment target vs. base SDK with TWTweetComposeViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I have set my base SDK to 6.0 and my Deployment Target to 6.0.

When I build, I get the following error. 
'TWTweetComposeViewController' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0

If I drop my Deployment Target down to 5.1 it compiles without error.  Since TWTweetComposeViewController is "Available in iOS 5.0 and later.", this seems opposite to what I was expecting.

I would just leave it like that but I am also using Social/Social.h which is only available in 6.0 and up and will be error prone for the 5.1 users.

This is the problematic line of code:

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]){
```

Racking my brain on this.  I'm hoping it is just some obscure setting I have missed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TWTweetComposeViewController is deprecated, because for iOS 6.0 there is a new framework to handle all social interactions called Social.framework. Inside there you can find similar functionality to post tweets via [SLComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205).

to solve your problem with iOS6 you have to options depending on what you support:

- Support iOS6 and above: Just use SLComposeViewController. Link framework Social.framework and done with it.
- Support iOS 5.x and above: Needs more work. First need to check if the SLComposeViewController exists (so you are in iOS 6.0), and then use it and present it, otherwise use the TWTweetComposeViewController for older iOS. Also you would need to link framework Social.framework as optional.

As a side note, if you support iOS 6 only, you can use same controller to post to facebook for free, so consider using facebook integration too.

Comment: Yeah, this was the problem.  If I had looked at the Social framework a little closer I would have saved myself some trouble.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of TWTweetComposeViewController use SLComposeViewController which is include in Social Framework

```
- (IBAction)SendTweet:(id)sender {
   if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
 {
    mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController         composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" THIS IS AN EXAMPLE",mySLComposerSheet.serviceType]];
    [mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    [mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.StackOverflow.com/"]];
    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
   [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    NSLog(@"dfsdf");
    NSString *output;
    switch (result) {
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            output = @"ACtionCancelled";
            break;
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            output = @"Post Successfull";
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter Message" message:output delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}];
}
```